# Issue to move a Google sheet from my drive to a shared Google drive folder in Java

Tags: google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

With a Google service account, I am able to create a Google sheet.  Next, I need to move  the newly created Google sheet to a shared Google drive folder, so other users can access it. Below is the block of codes.

```
        // Drive driveService = DriveServiceUtils.getDriveService();
        Drive   serviceDrive = new Drive.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(),
                GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
                requestInitializer)
                .setApplicationName("PSDrive")
                .build();

        // Retrieve the file ID of the newly created Google Sheet
        String sheetFileId = spreadsheet.getSpreadsheetId();

       File sheetFile = serviceDrive.files().get(sheetFileId).execute();
       File sheetFilevCurrparent = serviceDrive.files().get(sheetFileId).setFields("parents").execute();

       File sharedFolderId = serviceDrive.files().get("270ej6gDQdfsdfw1PuCsXFUlJj1OwJTe9nu").execute();
       List<String> parents = sheetFile.getParents();
       serviceDrive.files().update(sheetFileId, null)
                .setAddParents(String.valueOf(sharedFolderId))
                .setRemoveParents(String.join(",", parents))
                .execute();
```

When run the above codes, it just displays "null" in the output window.  I have checked the home/my drive of the service account and the Google sheet has been created.  However, the newly created sheet is not moved to the shared folder.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Tony

I am expecting the newly created Google sheet be moved to a shared folder on Google drive.